# What is meant by this limsup?

Tags: analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Currently I'm working through a proof in which occours the following limsup:

$\limsup_{||h||\to 0} |f(h)|$

In the internet I only found definitions for the following limits:
$\lim_{n \to \infty}$ and $\lim_{x \to \xi}$. Where can I find the proper definition?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=limsup) seems to be a good place to start looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Then 
$$
\limsup_{\|h\| \to 0} | f(h) | = 
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \ \sup_{\| h \| \leq \varepsilon} |f(h)|
$$
where $\varepsilon > 0$.